# How can i create a list of array form multiple array i already have with a classification in the end

Tags: python, arrays

So my main goal is to end up with a list of array of this look :

```
[ FFT(array1),S
  FFT (array2),M]
```

I have two folders one named S and one named M, I was able to read all the wav files inside both folders and did a Fourier transformation on both of them. I ended up with each one alone ( I used a for loop for each folder, the first folder has 3998 wav files the second has 2100 wav files)  here  is the code

```
for i in range ( 0,3998,+1) :
    
    FFTS = np.fft.rfft(zero1[i])
    print(FFTS)
for i in range ( 0,2100,+1) :
    
    FFT_M = np.fft.rfft(zero2[i])
    print(FFT_M)
```

Now how can i just put both FFTS and FFT_M in a list of array that should be in the end in the form

```
[ FFT(array1),S
  FFT (array2),M]
```